# Azure subnets for cloned Dev, Test, Product with common web server

Tags: azure, networking, subnet, vnet

I have 3 VMs (app, content, DB) that are part of an application deployment. I need to clone multiple copies of this VM set. There is a common web server for all sets that proxies requests to the app server in each set.

Because hostnames are duplicated, I believe I can put each SET of 3 VMs into their own subnet and prevent communication and hostname duplication.

The web server will be outside these subnets (I guess in its own subnet).

If you have multiple hosts with the same hostname in the same VNET, will they have the same internal DNS name? The fact that they are firewalled into separate subnets should prevent cross traffic?

The web server will proxy based on IP address, since hostname will not resolve easily.

An alternative is one web server per VM set, 4 servers per VNET. This will work, but means 25% more VMs to manage.

Anyone suggest the "typical" way a network engineer would architect this? (Yes this could be cross posted to networking group, but it is dependent upon Azure specifics as well as general network architecture).

Many thanks experts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple hosts with the same hostname and internal DNS name. These have to be unique. The alternative seems more favorable here.